# Dpkg is angry about uninstalling virtualbox 6.0 after installing from deb file

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dpkg

So I installed VirtualBox 6.0 from the deb file before learning that actually, I wanted version 5.2 (I have my reasons). Anyway, I attempted to remove virtualbox-6.0 using apt remove --purge and it failed with the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.0 (--remove):
 installed virtualbox-6.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

dpkg --remove --force-all virtualbox-6.0 did no different.
In my infinite wisdom, I decided to delete every trace of virtualbox I could find on my system, did so, and now virtualbox is gone from everything it had under /usr. Then I tried removing it, which still returned the same error. I was unable to install version 5.2 because it complained that another installation was still there. There is no trace of any processes running or files on my drive, yet this annoyingly persistent vbox is still in the way.
How do I get it to go away?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete output. Exit status 1 simply means that some subprocess failed.

Comment: @user535733 unfortunately, that error is generated by the package pre-removal `/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox-6.0.prerm` script failing, which is (usually a) shell script. Quite often the pre/post scripts do not report useful errors when they fail, alas.

Comment: @Steve Beattie two hours of googling later, the fix was to remove that script, which I missed originally.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem. I was unable to remove the package in a "normal" manner.
To solve it I had to manually delete all related files.
To do so I ran:
`$ dpkg -L virtualbox-6.0`
The output lists all files/folders owned by the package but there are also important folders such as `/usr/src` listed so **you cannot just delete everything with a pipe** like `dpkg -L virtualbox-6.0 | xargs rm -r`, you need to delete them 1 by one or folder by folder it goes quite fast.